# How to display the tick of the timer in C#

Tags: c#, timer

I want to know how can I achieve this goal?

```
    private void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
    //100 plus line of code here
    timer1.Stop();
}

int i = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    label1.text = i.toString();
}
```

I want to happen is that when I press the button the timer will run and display the time in label1.text and it will stop until it will reach the timer stop function

Comment: Don't `Stop` the timer in the button press unconditionally - *the timer may never fire in that case*. (It's a tad more complicated than this, but it actually requires work to get the WinForms time *to* fire if the UI thread is blocked.)

Comment: Side note: 100+ lines of code in one little section is very bad (unless this is simply a proof of concept.. even so it's very bad).

Comment: "Does not work"??? That's a terrible description of the problem.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead, hmm it has a switch which contains 100+ case :)

Comment: @SuiGo : Ouch. There's another question here.

Comment: @_@ the timer is my quest ion ^^

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Is it that you want to time the amount of time some code takes to execute?

Comment: If you are trying to see how much time btnProcess_Click takes (profile), you should look at using StopWatch.

Comment: @RogerStewart YESS, how?

Comment: Look at this : http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/57482-countdown-timer/ It may be useful for you

Comment: You should definitely consider strategies that would help reduce the the `switch` statement to something more manageable. There are established design patterns that could improve that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
//100 lines of code... 
label1.Text = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
```

???

Comment: wehn button was click the label will changed like 0.01->0.02->0.03 etc..until it finished?